# OmniAuth::NoSessionError - You must provide a session to use OmniAuth. (configured in devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

Hi I am learning how to use omniauth as backend for ember app.

when i run my application I get the below mentioned erroe
OmniAuth::NoSessionError - You must provide a session to use OmniAuth

on resue rails s my applicataion halts at line below.

```
  172: def call!(env) # rubocop:disable CyclomaticComplexity
    173:   unless env['rack.session']
    174:     error = OmniAuth::NoSessionError.new('You must provide a session to use OmniAuth.')
 => 175:     fail(error)
    176:   end
    177:
```

config/intializer/devise

```
Devise.setup do |config|

  config.mailer_sender = 'please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com'
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]
  config.http_authenticatable = true
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10
  config.reconfirmable = true
  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true
  config.password_length = 8..128
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
  config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
  config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html,:json]
  config.sign_out_via = :delete
  require 'omniauth-facebook'
  config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['8987087080'] , ENV['3d6a359a37c8780870dxxxx5'],:strategy_class => OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook
end
```

config/intializer/session_store.rb

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :disabled
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users
      resources :games
    end
  end

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  #devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  devise_for :users, controllers: { 
    omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks',
    sessions: 'sessions' , 
    registrations: "registrations",


  }
   devise_scope :user do 
    match 'users/sign_in', to: 'sessions#create', via: :post
    match 'api/v1/users' , to: 'registrations#create' , via: :post
  end

end
```

gemfile.rb

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'

platforms :ruby do # linux
  gem 'unicorn'
  gem 'foreman'
  gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
end
group :development, :test do
    gem 'compass'
    gem 'pry'
    gem 'pry-remote'
    gem 'pry-rails'
    gem 'pry-rescue'
    gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
    gem 'pry-byebug'
    gem 'guard'
    gem 'guard-livereload'
    gem 'guard-rails'
    gem 'guard-rspec'
    gem 'guard-cucumber'
    gem 'guard-zeus'
    gem 'rspec-rails'

end
group :production do
    #gem 'pg'
end

#authentication
gem 'cancan'
gem 'rolify'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '=1.4.0'
gem 'oauth2'



# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'
gem 'bootswatch-rails'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'



# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'


group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

#ember
gem "active_model_serializers"
gem "ember-source", "~>1.7.0"

#asyc http calls
gem 'hashie_rails'
gem "typhoeus"
gem "virtus"

#middleware
gem "rack-cors", require: 'rack/cors'



platforms :mswin do 
  gem "wdm", :group => [:development, :test]
end
#gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0'

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is because you disabled the session middleware (look at the output of `rake middleware`). Omniauth will not work without the session middleware.

You disabled it here: `Rails.application.config.session_store :disabled`

If you are trying to ditch session because you do not use it other than for Omniauth, then the only thing you can do is write your own middleware that *injects* `ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore` and possibly other necessary middlewares based on the URL (i.e. if the URL is `/auth/*`). Here is an example of what I use to achieve this (only uses session if URL path is not `/api/...`):

```
# /config/application.rb
config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, "SelectiveStack"

# /config/initializers/omniauth.rb
::OmniAuthConfig = Proc.new do
  provider :github, # ...
end

# /app/middleware/selective_stack.rb
class SelectiveStack
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    if env["PATH_INFO"].start_with?("/api/") # <--- Change URL path here
      @app.call(env)
    else
      middleware_stack.build(@app).call(env)
    end
  end

private
  def middleware_stack
    @middleware_stack ||= begin
      ActionDispatch::MiddlewareStack.new.tap do |middleware|
        # needed for OmniAuth
        middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
        middleware.use Rails.application.config.session_store, Rails.application.config.session_options
        middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder, &OmniAuthConfig
        # needed for Doorkeeper /oauth views
        middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In this example I only enable the session middleware when the URL does **not** start with `/api/`. You **will** still need to remove `Rails.application.config.session_store :disabled` and properly set up your session store, of course. In my example I use the cookie store. You might need to tweak my example based on which middleware you are missing in `rake middleware`. But if you're not doing this for performance reasons then just reenable the session middleware.

Comment: The console command to list middleware is `rake middleware` not `rack middleware`

Comment: This is a great technique also if you have an API "only" app that you also want to stick a simple /admin CRUD UI onto.

Answer (score 11):

> Into application.rb

```
...

config.api_only = true
config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_interslice_session'
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies # Required for all session management
config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, config.session_options
```

Comment: More about this https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth#integrating-omniauth-into-your-rails-api

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to disable Rails session cookie, but still have OmniAuth working is to leave the session enabled in the initializer (`initializers/session_store.rb`):

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app_session'
```

but disable it at the controller level, for all controllers:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :drop_session_cookie

  ...

  private

  def drop_session_cookie
    request.session_options[:skip] = true
  end
end
```