# How to create a custom middleware while using rails 5 in api-mode?

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-5, middleware, rails-admin

I'm trying to create a custom middleware in rails 5 in api-mode where for only routes that don't start with /api/... it will add back in

```
middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies::Session
```

This post shows how to do it in rails 4:
[OmniAuth::NoSessionError - You must provide a session to use OmniAuth. (configured in devise)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922343/omniauthnosessionerror-you-must-provide-a-session-to-use-omniauth-configur)

I'm trying to create a middleware like the accepted answer in the above post but when adding the

```
config.middleware.insert_before ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, "SelectiveStack"
```

to application.rb it throws an error saying it can't find SelectiveStack.

It also won't let me add a require or includes in the application.rb to access it, so I was wondering if anyone come across this or had any ideas?

I may just have the format wrong or have it in the wrong path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that ActionDispatch::ParamsParser from the other stackoverflow post middleware doesn't actually exist and the wording of the error was a bit confusing.

So basically to get it working you can either put your middleware before an actual existing middleware or just use

```
config.middleware.use
```

instead of

```
config.middleware.insert_before
```